# Getting team name, count of victories, count of played

Tags: mysql, join, count

i have such a database :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opponents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `opponents` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Team 1'),
(2, 'Team 2'),
(3, 'Team 3'),
(4, 'Team 4'),
(5, 'Team 5'),
(6, 'Team 6'),
(7, 'Team 7'),
(8, 'Team 8');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `winner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `statut` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id` (`game_id`),
  KEY `winner_id` (`winner_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;

INSERT INTO `matches` (`id`, `game_id`, `winner_id`, `score`, `statut`) VALUES
(1, 2, 8, '2-3', 3),
(2, 2, 0, '', 1),
(3, 2, 0, '', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `odds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opponent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),
  KEY `opponent_id` (`opponent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=63 ;


INSERT INTO `odds` (`id`, `datetime`, `match_id`, `opponent_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, '2013-11-05 16:33:26', 1, 1, 1),
(2, '2013-11-05 16:33:26', 1, 8, 1),
(3, '2013-11-05 16:50:19', 2, 2, 1),
(4, '2013-11-05 16:50:19', 2, 3, 1),
(5, '2013-11-05 16:51:11', 3, 5, 1),
(6, '2013-11-05 16:51:11', 3, 7, 1);
```

I want to get a list of all opponents with a count of their victories, and their total played matchs.
I have no problem for the list of opponents and their victories, wrote such a query :

```
SELECT `o`.`id`, `o`.`name`, COUNT(m.id) AS victories FROM (`opponents` o) LEFT JOIN `matches` m ON `m`.`winner_id` = `o`.`id` GROUP BY `o`.`id` ORDER BY `victories` DESC
```

But i have a problem to retrieve their total played matchs. The hard part is opponents are not stored directly in the MATCHES table, but in ODDS table. I tried this query, but it return me a total of 7 played match for Team #1, when she played only 1 match (and won it) :

```
 SELECT `o`.`id`, `o`.`name`, COUNT(m.id) AS victories, COUNT(m2.id) AS played FROM (`estv_opponents` o) LEFT JOIN `estv_matches` m ON `m`.`winner_id` = `o`.`id` LEFT JOIN `estv_odds` ON `estv_odds`.`opponent_id` = `o`.`id` LEFT JOIN `estv_matches` m2 ON `m2`.`id` = `estv_odds`.`match_id` AND m2.statut = 3 GROUP BY `o`.`id`, `estv_odds`.`opponent_id` ORDER BY `victories` DESC
```

In my third join, "m2.statut = 3" is here to specify that the match has been played and is over. That's what I want, a count of played matches, not a count of all matchs (some are not played yet)

Any help would be appreciated, i dont understand how I should build this query.

My expected output is an array like this one :

an array such this one :

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Team #8"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Team #1"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Team #2"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Team #3"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Team #4"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Team #5"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "Team #6"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Team #7"
    ["victories"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["played"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `opponents are not stored directly in the MATCHES table` Can I suggest that there's a flaw in your design then?!

Comment: Your expected output ?

Comment: @Shafeeq : see original post, I edited with expected output at the end

Comment: @Strawberry : This design looked to be the best for my needs. My global project is a betting site, with odds. On each match, I can update odds of both teams and I wanted to keep logs of previous odds. So I couldn't just add 4 fields in my MATCHES tables (opponent_1_id, opponent_2_id, opponent_1_odds, opponent_2_odds). Do you think of a better db design that would help me keeping logs of odds change, and would permit to get victories and played count more easily ?

Comment: `matches` is a fact table. Logically, a table of that name might record who played against whom. What types of betting are we concerned with; straight bets, propositions, all, etc.?

Comment: I think your sample data and desired output is not matching. how can Team #4 played a match even there is no enter for them in odds table and matches table

Comment: @Strawberry : I dont understand what "straight bets" and "propositions" are (i'm french). Right now, odds are not working yet, or v1 of the project will just let users bet on a winner (and pick a score : 3-0, 3-1, 2-3, etc). But later, we will add the odds features. We will have bookmakers that will daily update odds of teams. Let's say yesterday, odds of team#1 and team#2 were 1.3 and 1.7 and today, they are 1.2 and 1.8. So if a user browse the website today, it will display 1.2 and 1.8, and he will pick one of these 2 odds and bet an amount on it. And we want or database to be ready for that

Comment: @dkkumargoyal : maybe my desired output does not match, I did it quick. But the idea is here : a list of teams registered in database, as far as they appear in a match (they do not appear in MATCHES table, but in ODDS table, which is linked to MATCHES table by odds.match_id = matches.id). And for all these teams, a field containing the toal victories and the total played (m.statut = 3). Ofc, total victories can't be greater than total played.

Comment: @dkkumargoyal : mhh sorry, i didn't understand. I shortened some of the tables data for thie thread. My MATCHES table contains 28 rows (every team plays against every other team) for a total of 28 matches. I also shortened the ODDS table. Logically, my ODDS table contains 56 rows (2 rows for 1 match, 1 for each team)

Comment: ok got the played condition as m.statut = 3 please check the SQL in my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following SQL if it works for you.

```
select op.id, op.name, sum(if(o.opponent_id = m.winner_id, 1, 0)) victories, sum(if(m.statut = 3,1,0)) played from opponents as op left join odds o on op.id = o.opponent_id left join matches m on o.match_id = m.id group by op.id order by victories desc;
```

Comment: really smart. and it works great : ) Thank you very much for that time invested in building that query.